# PHP MySQL making the values as a null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code that I'm struggling to figure out. Essentially I want the code to check if variables equals a certain value and if they do then I want the DB to update with NULL, if it doesn't equal the value then it will write the variable to the DB.

**PHP**

```
$noteid     = $_POST['id'];
$title      = $_POST['title'];
$content    = $_POST['content'];

if ($title == 'Type your title'){
    $title = null;
} else {
    $title = '$title';
}
if ($content == 'Type your note'){
    $content = null;
} else {
    $content = '$content';
}
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE notes SET title=$title, note=$content WHERE id='$noteid' AND uid = '$_SESSION[id]'");
```

Comment: What is the error you're running up against?

Comment: is your schema allowing null values?

Comment: You may consider using the placeholder attribute in your form.

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems:

First is solution to what you're asking:

> if it doesn't equal the value then it will write the variable to the DB.

Remove both of your else blocks because they are are not really required.  You already have the `$title` set from the `$_POST` global.  Secondly you are wrapping `$title` within single quotes, what that is going to do is make the content within single quotes literal, so `$title` won't get interpolated.  For string interpolation you want to use double quotes, i.e. `"$title"` if you had to.

Your code updated after removing else blocks:

```
$noteid     = $_POST['id'];
$title      = $_POST['title'];
$content    = $_POST['content'];

if ($title == 'Type your title'){
    $title = null;
} 

if ($content == 'Type your note'){
    $content = null;
}
```

Second problem is you are using deprecated `mysql_` functions.  You should consider switching to using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if ($title == 'Type your title'){
    $title = null;
} else {
    $title = '$title';
}
if ($content == 'Type your note'){
    $content = null;
} else {
    $content = '$content';
}
```

to

```
if ($title == 'Type your title'){
    $title = null;
} else {
    $title = $title;
}
if ($content == 'Type your note'){
    $content = null;
} else {
    $content = $content;
}`
```

or as   **Will Harrison** said remove the else code and make it

```
if ($title == 'Type your title'){
        $title = null;
    } 
    if ($content == 'Type your note'){
        $content = null;
    } 
    `
```

Comment: or just take out the else.